# Get horizontal position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, position

I am using `t.position().left`, but it does not appear to include the `margin`, `padding`, or `border` of other elements to its left. How can I get the position as it appears to the user? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get position in document (not in parent) you can use `$(....).offset()`

Comment: This seems to overcompensate by > 100px. A parent `div` has `position:relative`, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can u please upload some more precise description of what you want to achieve? Or at least some picture with markers what you want to measure. `Offset` always returns position relative to the document, so I see that you don't want that position but some other that I don't know since you described your problem very shortly.